# Stateful or Stateless service for processing servicebus queues

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-servicebus-queues, service-fabric-stateful

I have a Session enabled Azure servicebus queue. I need some form of service that can read from the queue and process them and save the result (in memory for later retrieval).  We are using azure servicefabric in our current architecture. I got few questions regarding which one to choose Stateful or Stateless service.

If I use Stateful service, then based on the documentation my understanding is, service will be running on 1 primary node (assuming 1 partition) and 2 active secondary nodes. That means, if I have a 10 node Service fabric cluster, then this stateful service will be utilizing only one node (VM) primarily.

So if I add a listener to this stateful service  to read messages from Queues then that service on primary node will read messages from queues and all other remaining 9 nodes wont be able to utilized. Is this correct?

Whereas if I use Stateless service, I can create instances on all 10 nodes and all of them could listen to the message in Queues and process them in parallel. However, I will loose the option to save the results.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I add a listener to this stateful service to read messages from Queues then that service on primary node will read messages from queues and all other remaining 9 nodes wont be able to utilized. Is this correct?

That is correct. With stateful service scenario, only the primary replica will have it's listener executed, and work will be done. Other replicas *can* be used in read-only mode, but they would not be writing anything into reliable collections.

> Whereas if I use Stateless service, I can create instances on all 10 nodes and all of them could listen to the message in Queues and process them in parallel.

Exactly. Stateless services can perform their work in parallel and no state is persisted. That's also the reason whey there's no reliable collection available for this Service Fabric model.

> However, I will loose the option to save the results.

Not necessarily true. You could still save your data in a centralized/shared DB, just like you'd do with stateless solutions in the past (for example Cloud Services, or a Azure WebApp).

What you should ask yourself is what problem are you solving. If you have data sharding, the Statful makes more sense. If you don't have data sharding and/or you need to scale out your processing power, rather that scale up, Stateless is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'm trying to avoid writing results to external store (latency and maintenance) I thought I could use the service fabric feature to store results in the memory for later use. Looks like my best option is to stick with stateless for processing queues and create another stateful service for just storing/retrieving results. Does this make sense or am I making it overly complicated?

Comment: With SF's reliable collections, keep in mind it should only be used as hot data. And as hot data, it needs to be stored in cold storage for backup/restoration purposes in case things go wrong.